# Браузер не обрабатывает событие

Tags: javascript, ajax, события, браузер

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся со следующей проблемой. У меня есть код на JavaScript,

```
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open('GET', 'books.json', true);
        xhttp.send(null);
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            var res = eval('(' + xhttp.responseText + ')');
            var r = function (index, tag) { return res.books[index][tag] }
            author.innerHTML += r(3, 'author');
        }
```

который должен выполяняться при нажатии кнопки на веб-странице. Однако, когда я нажимаю кнопку, ничего не выполняется. Тогда я лезу в отладчик и начинаю построчно прогонять этот код. И к концу прогона результат уже есть на экране. Какова причина того, что результат отладчика разнится с результатом? И как это исправить? Если что, данная проблема встречается на браузерах Mozila, Maxthon, IE.

Comment: Еще бы код страницы в той ее части, где размещена кнопка, получить.

Comment: <body>
    <input type="button" id="button" value="Start">
    <div id="author"> </div>
</body>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причина - то, что на момент выполнения скрипта DOM-элемент `author` еще не построен, а отладчик дает задержку и он успевает за это время построиться, нужно использовать window.load или просто разместить скрипт после элемента.

Еще одна проблема - стоит использовать `getElementById`, потому что не все браузеры получают элементы по id'ам автоматически.